# Определение предложения в начальной школе

Tags: грамматика, методика

**Предложение — это слово или группа слов, которые связаны по смыслу и выражают законченную мысль** (из учебника для 2-го класса).

*Ребенок ходит по комнате и повторяет определение. Это очень хорошая, послушная и дисциплинированная девочка, но почему-то выучить **это** никак не получается. Именно  это конкретное высказывание кажется ей бессмысленным и ничего не выражает.*

*Мама на кухне занимается делами, изредка прислушиваясь к процессу. И вдруг слышит, что тем же монотонным голосом дочка повторяет: Я ненавижу русский язык. Я ненавижу русский язык.*

*Мама встревожена, что делать? Её девочка так мечтала учиться в школе, а дети должны любить родную речь. Может быть, нужна игровая форма, чтобы интересно было, или еще что-то нужно?* И нет ли сказок, в которых известные герои детских книг учат грамматику?

А у меня к этому определению **такие вопросы.**

1) Могут ли дети понять значение  двух однокоренных слов ***мысль*** и ***смысл,*** присутствующих в одном тексте?

2)  Мысль — многозначное слово, но здесь, вероятно,  имеется в виду **результат процесса мышления в форме суждения.**  Тогда получается, что законченная мысль — это законченное суждение. А это что такое?  Не каждый взрослый поймет, о какой законченности идет речь.

3)  В действительности же грамматическое предложение  начинается там, где **процессуальный признак (действие или состояние) относят к предмету,** но об этом  детям еще рано говорить. Но из этого же  не следует, что они должны  учить наизусть непонятные слова.

Возможно, **детская психика вообще еще не готова** к изучению грамматики по существующим МЕТОДИКАМ. Детям  такого возраста  хорошо бы **на практике** изучать язык, писать мини-сочинения, изучать лексику, чтобы понять красоту родной речи. Возрастной критерий здесь очень важен, об этом и психологи говорят. Научите младших школьников сначала ЛЮБИТЬ русский язык, а для подробного изучения граматики еще будет время.

И вопрос: **Можно ли дать другое определение предложению в начальной школе или это определение вполне корректно?**

Примечание

**Откуда материал?** В одной московской школе, в одном (втором) классе учатся две сестрички-кузины, причем совершенно разного характера. А  школьные истории мне иногда рассказывают их мамы по телефону. Эта история случилась совсем недавно, в сентябре 2019 года.

Кстати, еще до начала учебного года детям было велено приобрести тетрадь в 48 листов. Как  оказалось, она была предназначена для записи подобных определений при изучении русского языка. Все определения нужно знать наизусть.

Comment: Возможно, я чегой-то не понимаю. В заголовке: _определение предложени**Я**._ В конце вопроса: _определение предложени**Ю**._ Я предполагаю (только предполагаю!), что падеж должен быть одним и тем же. Или нет?

Comment: @Sharon опытный преподаватель РЯ просит вас ответиь на несколько вопросов относительно источника вашего текста. Пожалуйста, хотя бы  прочитайте всего один пост (первую часть) http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=6844&start=80#p485873

Answer (score 1):

*Предложение — это связанные смыслом слова в составе одного выражения.*

Вопросы второго ряда — количество слов, о наличии мысли и её законченности, — должны быть до поры отложены.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше мнение.

Answer (score 1):

Я пропускаю всю увертюру про ребенка и смысл мысли... Ибо субъективно.

Вот о чем готов порассуждать.

> Можно ли дать другое определение предложению в начальной школе или это
>   определение вполне корректно?

Во-первых, мне не нравится такая постановка. Два разных вопроса, которые не должны быть соединены союзом.

Во-вторых. Определений можно дать хоть на три книги. Зачем?

Во-третьих. Что такое "корректное определение"? В логике корректным считается определение, если оно внутренне непротиворечиво. В данном определении не вижу ничего противоречивого, даже внешне, не то что внутренне.

Давайте поставим вопрос ребром. Зачем детям вообще определения? Только для того, чтобы они знали, что есть определяемое слово - и не пугались при встрече с ним. Дальше уже надо включать логику. Например, если предложение закончено, то надо ставить точку. Если дитя не знает, что такое предложение, ему бесполезно внушать правила его оформления. Поможет ребенку данное определение понять, что такое предложение - все, вопрос исчерпан. Не поможет - надо объяснять другими способами.

Все-таки практическая лингвистика - не математика, определения не абсолютизируются.

Данное определение само по себе не вызывает отторжения, то есть вопрос чисто в плоскости практической его применимости.  И оно вполне себе применимо.

Куда хуже было бы, вспомни определения, с которыми приходилось сталкиваться школьникам лет 50 назад.
Я, конечно, не помню точно, как тогда определялось конкретно "предложение". Но уровень был примерно такой: *"Предложение это кусок текста, начинающийся с заглавной буквы и кончающийся точкой"*. И вот такую галиматью приходилось запоминать. Причем понятно оно было как раз вполне. Вот только толку в нем не было никакого.

*Зубрить определения (и правила) не надо. Их надо понять. Зубрить имеет смысл разве что специфические исключения из правил.*

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше мнение.

Answer (score 0):

В лингвистике существуют два понятия — предложение  и  высказывание, которые относятся к одной синтаксической конструкции.

**Предложение** —  грамматическая конструкция, ее основное свойство  — это предикативность.

**Высказывание** —  семантическая структура, которая используется для передачи информации при речевом общении. При анализе высказывания используются такие понятия как тема (о чем говорится) и рема (что говорится).

В  школе предложение определяется  **по семантическому принципу**, но затем изучается как  **грамматическая структура**.

Можно дать два определения  (для начальной и старшей школы):

(1) Предложение — это **группа связанных между собой слов**, которые содержат сообщение, вопрос или побуждение к действию.

(2) Предложение — это **минимальная речевая единица**, имеющая коммуникативное значение, которая содержит сообщение, вопрос или побуждение к действию.